# How to rename file with google drive api v3? electron, nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, electron

for v2, we can get an example how to rename file with google drive API. here's the link
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch#examples
here's how we can rename a file with v2 in javascript

```js
/**
 * Rename a file.
 *
 * @param {String} fileId <span style="font-size: 13px; ">ID of the file to rename.</span><br> * @param {String} newTitle New title for the file.
 */
function renameFile(fileId, newTitle) {
  var body = {'title': newTitle};
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.patch({
    'fileId': fileId,
    'resource': body
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('New Title: ' + resp.title);
  });
}
```

i need to create function like example from v2 with electron and nodejs.
here's what i've done so far [mfm-gdrive](https://github.com/dhanyn10/mfm-gdrive)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using in the question and what exactly is not working? @dhanyn10

Comment: i can't find any example for function renaming file in v3. @ale13

Comment: Now I noticed that you wanted the script for Node.js. From your question, I had thought that you wanted the script for Javascript. This is my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I understood my answer was not suitable for your question. So I have to delete it because I don't want to confuse other users. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to rename a file using the Drive API v3, you will have to use the `Files:update` request, like this:

```
function renameFile(auth) {
  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  var body = {'name': 'NEW_NAME'};
  drive.files.update({
    fileId: 'ID_OF_THE_FILE',
    resource: body,
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    else {
      console.log('The name of the file has been updated!');
    }
  });
}
```

You can also simulate the `update` request by using the Drive API v3 Reference [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update).

As for examples, I suggest you check the Drive API v3 Node.js Quickstart [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) which you can later adapt such that is suits your needs accordingly.

#### Reference

- [Drive API v3 Files:update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update);
- [Drive API v3 Files and folders overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-files);
- [Drive API v3 Node.js Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs).